# How do I create a rolling monthly datetime index for pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, datetimeindex

I have a DatetimeIndex in pandas and I want to convert it to a rolling DatetimeIndex using the last date in the series.

So if I create a sample datetime index:

```
dates=pd.DatetimeIndex(pd.date_range(dt(2017,10,1),dt(2018,02,02)))
```

#### An example

Input: DatetimeIndex with all dates in the above range:

```
dates
2017-10-01 
2017-10-02  
     .            
     .            
2018-02-01   
2018-02-02
```

Desired Output: DatetimeIndex with only the 2nd of every month (as that is the last date in the input):

```
dates
2017-10-02 
2017-11-02
2017-12-02
2018-01-02
2018-02-02
```

#### Attempts

I've tried

```
dates[::-1][::30]
```

and also

```
dates[dates.apply(lambda x: x.date().day==2)]
```

Unfortunately months can differ by 30 or 31 days so the first way doesn't work  and while the second method works for days in range 1-30, for the 31st it skips every other month. So, for example, if I had:

```
dates
2017-10-01 
2017-10-02  
     .            
     .            
2018-01-31
```

I would want:

```
dates
2017-10-31 
2017-11-30          
2017-12-31   
2018-01-31
```

while the second method skips November as it doesn't have a 30th.

Is there any way to use RelativeDelta to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `.is_month_end` functionality in Pandas. This gives an array of boolean values – `True` if the date is a month-end, false if otherwise.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

dates=pd.Series(pd.date_range('2017-10-1','2017-12-31'))
print(dates[dates.is_month_end])
```

**Output**

```
DatetimeIndex(['2017-10-31', '2017-11-30', '2017-12-31'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

This will help you filter things.

Comment: But any date could be the last date, the 31st was just an example

Comment: yes, `is_month_end` captures the last date for that month, so 28 for Feb, 30 for Nov and so on...

Comment: Yes, but I dont necessarily need a rolling index of month ends. Could be the 2nd or 3rd of every month which is_month_end won't cover.

Comment: @user2997582 your question is not clear enough then, please be more specific. From what I got by reading your question `is_month_end` is exactly what you need